# Члены предложения

Tags: предложение

Здравствуйте! Ответте, пожалуйста, на два вопроса.

1. У обстоятельства (как члена предложения) может быть определение? Например: "Корабль шёл в родной порт". "В родной порт" - это обстоятельство или "в порт" - это обстоятельство, а "родной" - это определение?
2. У определения может быть дополнение? Например: "Корабль, качающейся на высоких волнах, шёл в порт". "Качающейся на высоких волнах" - это определение, или "качающейся" - это определение, "на волнах" - это дополнение? Тогда "высоких" - это определение (определение у определения)? Спасибо.

Comment: @avtx, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: >Василий Аксенов. Круглые сутки нон-стоп // «Новый Мир», 1976  
― Тогда ответьте мне по-человечески, ― попросил Москвич. ― Есть ли тут смысл, а?

Answer (score 2):

"Корабль, качающийся на высоких волнах, шёл в родной порт".

шёл (куда?) в порт - обстоятельство

в порт (какой?) родной - определение

корабль (какой?) качающийся на высоких волнах - обособленное определение, выраженное причастным оборотом

качающийся (на чем?) на волнах - дополнение

на волнах (каких?) высоких - определение

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ

Обособленный оборот не образуют словосочетания с подчиняющим словом и присоединяется к предложению на основе полупредикативной связи. Поэтому разбор оборота делается отдельно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Простите, но мне кажется, что в нём ошибка. "Качающийся (на чём? или Где?) на волнах - я думаю, что это обстоятельство, т.к. указывает на место, а не на предмет.
Вот например: "Размахивающий (чем?) флагом. "Флагом" - это дополнение. 
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.
Спасибо.

Comment: Существует такое понятие, как морфологизованные/неморфологизованные члены предложения. Например, морфологизованное подлежащее - это сущ. в И.п. или местоимение. Морфологизованным обстоятельством является наречие. А вот предложно-падежные формы существительных часто бывают синкретичными (совмещающими несколько значений), и в глагольных сочетаниях они могут совмещать значения дополнений и обстоятельств, что мы и видим на нашем примере: на волнах - где? на чем?

Comment: Мне кажется, что вариант дополнения в этом случае подходит больше, сравнить: качаться на качелях, качаться на волнах, существительное дополняет значение глагола. А обстоятельство, в соответствии со своим названием, указывает на сопутствующие обстоятельства действия: место, время, причину и др. Например: я люблю качаться на волнах в море - здесь есть и обстоятельство, и дополнение.

Answer (score 0):

Полностью согласен с Софией: качающийся (на чем?) на волнах - дополнение. Т.к обычно качаются на чем-либо, а не где-то. Т.к. здесь описывается не место, где происходит действие, а при помощи чего происходит действие. Т.е. действие происходит с помощью волн.

Comment: Ещё раз, спасибо! Мне-то стало понятно, а как теперь это детям объяснить? ))) Можно ещё один вопрос? Как правильно ответить на вопрос - "Сколько частей речи в русском языке?" Везде пишут по-разному. Где-то причастия и деепричастия "учитывают", а где-то нет. Помогите, пожалуйста, снять этот вопрос раз и на всегда.

Comment: В школьной морфологии 7 самостоятельных(знаменательных)частей речи:имя существительное, имя прилагательное. имя числительное,местоимение, глагол (к нему относятся 2 глагольные формы - деепричастие и причастие),наречие,слова категории состояния;3 служебных части речи - предлог, союз, частицы(к ним примыкают этикетные слова"спасибо","пожалуйста"и пр.) + особый разряд слов - междометие и звукоподражательные слова.

Comment: Это понятно, спасибо, кстати, за ответ. А если в тесте (ненавижу тесты) будет вопрос "Сколько частей речи в русском языке" и варианты ответов: "7", "10", "12" и "в русском языке частей речи нет". Где ставить галочку? Ну или - "Где вы поставили бы галочку?" Спасибо.

P.S. Поймите меня правильно, что - это не шутка! Мне моим детям (4-й и 5-й класс)как объяснить?

Answer (score 0):

"качающейся на высоких волнах" - это причастный оборот, который является определением. Все в него входящие части речи подчеркиваются одинаково: волнистой линией,т.е. являются определением. А рассуждение (качающийся (на чем?) на волнах;на волнах (каких?) высоких) подтверждает, что слова относятся к причастию и представляют собой  причастный оборот.

Comment: Т.е. наличие определения у обстоятельства сомнений не вызывает ((куда?)в порт - обстоятельство, в порт (какой?) родной - определение) - это уже хорошо. С этим разобрались.
Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какое-либо правило, которое чётко говорит о том, что "весь" причастный оборот является определением. Спасибо.

Comment: Что значит "наличие определения у обстоятельства"? Формулировка такая возможна? А правило есть  в учебнике 6 класса. Со схемами, на которых прич.оборот подчеркнут волнистой линией.

Comment: Формулировка, "Наличие определения у обстоятельства", возможна. Например: "Это было тёмной ночью". "Тёмной ночью" - это обстоятельство или "ночью" - это обстоятельство, а "тёмной" - это определение?

Comment: Или вот ещё пример:"Шёл быстрым шагом". (Шёл как?, каким образом?) "Быстрым шагом" - это обстоятельство или (шёл как?) шагом - обстоятельство, (Шагом каким?) быстрым - это определение?

Comment: Второстепенные члены являются присловными распространителями главных или ДРУГИХ ВТОРОСТЕПЕННЫХ ЧЛЕНОВ и связаны с ними подчинительной связью - согласованием, управлением или примыканием. (Наряду с присловными распространителями, существуют неприсловные распространители - детерминанты и дуплексивы). Из этого следует, что обстоятельство может быть распространено определением.

Comment: Причастный оборот - это ОБОСОБЛЕННОЕ  определение, он не является присловным распространителем и не образует  словосочетания с предметным сущ., хотя формально связан с ним. Причастный оборот присоединяется к предложению на основе полупредикативной связи

Comment: Спасибо, София. Теперь помогите, пожалуйста, определиться с обстоятельствами. Вот тут написали (да и я такие примеры встречал), что весь (по крайней мере обособленный) причастный оборот в предложении является определением. Я не специалист в русском языке, поэтому, пожалуйста, объясните по-проще. Ещё раз, спасибо.

Comment: Рассмотрим примеры:(1) Окруженный деревьями дом не виден со стороны.(2) Окруженный деревьями, дом не виден со стороны. Здесь обособление факультативное - при обособлении мы придаем обороту обстоятельственное значение. "Окруженный деревьями" - это причастный оборот, то есть причастие с зависимыми словами. Если оборот не обособляется, то причастие относится с сущ. "дом" (является ПРИСЛОВНЫМ распространителем). Тогда разбор каждого слова делается отдельно: окруженный - определение, деревьями - дополнение.

Comment: Если оборот обособляется, то он представляет собой самостоятельную ЕДИНУЮ синтаксическую конструкцию. Почему это так? Формально причастие "окруженный" по-прежнему согласуется со словом "дом", но вместе со своим распространителем "деревьями"  относится КО ВСЕМУ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЮ. Фактически обособленный оборот близок по своей структуре к придаточному определительному предложению: Дом, который был окружен деревьями, не был виден со стороны.