# Обстоятельство или дополнение, или как отличить обстоятельство от дополнения?

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения, дополнение, обстоятельство

> Вот конёк по косогору  
>  Поднялся на эту гору.

Вопрос таков: *по косогору* — обстоятельство или дополнение?

Как мне кажется, здесь дополнение, поскольку вопросы обстоятельства места не согласуются с *по косогору*.

Тем не менее один человек утверждает, что, несмотря на отсутствие согласованности, здесь — обстоятельство места.

И раз я уже поднял этот вопрос, то подниму другой: как отличить обстоятельство от дополнения?

*Сижу (где?) в парке.* — 100% обстоятельство.  
*Сижу (где? на чём?) на стуле.* — непонятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вместо вступления**

Некоторые темы так часто обсуждались, что кажутся «замусоренными» как разными мнениями, так и разными  подходами к решению задачи.  Здесь тоже  можно использовать метод «чистого сознания», то есть ничего не читать, в том числе свои ответы, а использовать минимум исходных данных: словари и современные определения терминов, которым можно доверять. Без этого проводить дискуссию просто не имеет смысла.

1. **Дополнение** — это второстепенный член предложения, называющий лицо, **предмет** или явление, на который **распространяется действие** или по отношению к которому проявляется признак.

**Обстоятельство** — это второстепенный член предложения, который относится к слову со значением действия или признака и обозначает **качественные и количественные характеристики** этого действия или признака (**способ осуществления действия,** степень интенсивности действия или проявления признака), а также различные **внешние обстоятельства** осуществления действия (время, причину, условие и т.д.).

Кустова Г.И  Синтаксис современного русского языка,  стр. 81

[https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

2. Таким образом, **дополнение**  дополняет действие, когда оно происходит при взаимодействии **с объектом**. Но тот же объект можно посчитать **способом осуществления действия**, тогда это будет **обстоятельством**.  В этом плане и нужно делать выбор.

Например: ***идти по дороге.*** Идти (где?)  по дороге – это выбор пути (по дороге, по тропинке). Мы не говорим «идти по чему», хотя наступаем ногами на эту дорогу.

Из словаря: **ПОДНЯТЬСЯ**,  1. Переместиться **куда-л. вверх.** П. на крышу. П. на лифте. П. на пригорок. П. на смотровую площадку. Пар поднялся над озером. Орлы поднялись над горою.

***Подняться по косогору*** – это подняться вверх  (подняться на гору, куда?).  Есть ли здесь объект взаимодействия? Скорее всего, нет, как и в случае дороги.  Мы поднимаемся **с помощью косогора**, поэтому скажем: подняться (как?) по косогору, обстоятельство образа действия.

Можно подняться на лифте, по эскалатору, это тоже способ осуществления действия, хотя мы используем  для этого объект.

2. ***Сидеть на стуле*** (где? на чем?)

Из словаря: **СИДЕТЬ**, 1. Находиться в вертикальном положении, при котором туловище **опирается на что-л.** своей нижней частью, а ноги согнуты или вытянуты; **занимать место** для сидения где-либо.

Уже в словарной статье обозначены варианты: мы опираемся на объект (дополнение) или этот объект расположен в каком-то месте (обстоятельство).

Вот примеры: Ты **на чем** любишь сидеть, на стуле или на диване (на каком предмете)?  **Где** ты будешь сидеть, на стуле или на диване (выбор места)?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. На стр. 81 нет тех определений, которые Вы написали — по-моему, Вы скинули не ту ссылку.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Как у нас говорится, не за что, но возможно это так и есть. По ссылке нужно посмотреть только  определение терминов (дополнение и обстоятельство), это стр. 80 и 81. Надеюсь, вы понимаете, что  когда  люди обсуждают что-либо, то они должны сначала обсудить терминологию, иначе будут говорить  о разных вещах. Если нет согласия в терминах, значит, можно гарантировать, что разговор будет напрасным.

Comment: Я, в принципе, и не собираюсь проводить здесь или где-либо ещё дискуссию. Мне всего-то нужно разобраться в вопросе, но ответы по этому поводу у всех, как всегда, разные. Например, ответ Людмилы: «Название подобрали (для чего?) для этой деревни красивое. - дополнение, объект действия "подобрали"…». — Как мне кажется, здесь обстоятельство цели, а не дополнение. И ещё, если Вы не против, вопрос: что можно считать предметом? «Он взбежал (по чему?) по лестнице. - Лестница - объект, он по ней бежал, топтал её» (Людмила). — Можно ли лестницу считать предметом? Тут дополнение или обстоятельство?

Answer (score 3):

**Комментарий к  заданным вопросам**

Давайте разберемся. Ко всему сказанному мною ранее я могу сразу добавить следующее: **доверяйте вопросам.** Иногда по тому **естественному** вопросу, который мы используем в нашей речи чисто интуитивно,  ориентироваться легче, чем по каким-то логическим размышлениям.

1. **Название подобрали (для чего?) для этой деревни красивое.**

Связь двойная:  глагол задает падеж двум существительным (прямому объекту и косвенному): (1) подобрали что?  (2) подобрали для чего?  для какого объекта. Здесь, конечно, дополнение: как назвали объект, для какого объекта подобрали название, чему подобрали название.

Но в данном случае  вопрос вас, кажется, ввел в заблуждение: обстоятельство цели отвечает на такие вопросы: **для чего** ты приехал? **зачем** ты приехал? Мы же не скажем: зачем деревне подобрали название.

2. **Он взбежал (по чему?) по лестнице.**  Вот здесь придется делать выбор по естественному вопросу: как или по чему? по объекту или с помощью объекта (предмет и объект – это одно и то же).

Очевидно, надо учитывать **семантику глагола и ситуацию в целом.** В предыдущем варианте  (подняться по косогору)  вопрос «как?» звучит естественно, здесь же он кажется неуместным. В доме подняться на этаж можно **двумя способами**: по лестнице и на лифте. Это выбор способа действия, тогда это обстоятельство: **подняться (как?) по лестнице.** А вот взбежать можно только по лестнице, тут без вариантов, поэтому вопрос «как?» не подходит, **это дополнение (по чему?).**

Допустим,  мы убедили себя в правильности нашего решения, но ведь придется убеждать и других. И вот чтобы не вступать в длинные разговоры, удобно использовать **определение терминов,** тогда к вам вопросов не будет – оспаривать терминологию никому не захочется.

3. **По поводу дискуссии.** Здесь мне некорректным кажется множество **семантических оттенков,** которые рассматриваются отдельно и для каждого случая подбирается решение. Предварительно любую семантику надо **обобщить**, то есть свести ее к двум вариантам в соответствии с определением. В нашем случае это **«посредством объекта» или  «взаимодействуя с объектом».**

Кроме того, мне не  нравятся примеры, которые вы обсуждали:  они **неестественные, надуманные.** Это совершенно бесполезное занятие. Только в естественной речи мы можем определить функцию дополнения или обстоятельства, пользуясь строгим определением, иначе это будут просто **фантазии на тему**.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Теперь я более-менее могу отличить обстоятельство от дополнения. Осталось лишь довести алгоритм до автоматизма. Однако не понятны последние строчки: «…они неестественные, надуманные». — В каком смысле? «Только в естественной речи мы можем определить функцию дополнения или обстоятельства, пользуясь строгим определением, иначе это будут просто фантазии на тему». — Речь идёт о разговорном стиле? Если да, то почему, хотя, чую, на это уйдёт ещё один длинный комментарий, возможно даже длиннее этого, так что, если Вам трудно, не утруждайте себя.

Comment: Спасибо, я не буду себя утруждать. Здесь я говорю об общем приципе для всех примеров. Если вы их составляете сами, то делаете это намеренно, согласно своей логике, и здесь ошибки возможны и совершаются  часто.  В художественных произведениях, в нашей  бытовой речи пользователи ориентируются на интуицию, не задумываясь особо о том, как они составляют предложение..  Это естественная речь.  Вот вы обсуждаете примеры: думать на стуле, продавать на стуле.  Откуда они, что там за контекст, что за ситуация. Всё это имеет значение, решение может быть разным.

Comment: Забыл сказать спасибо — спасибо.

Comment: @ПростоЧел  Кроме спасибо в комментариях отвечающие могут получить от Вас "плюсик" в виде стрелочки (треугольника) вверх, а тот ответ, который был наиболее полезен, может быть принят еще и галочкой.

Answer (score 0):

```
Сидеть в парке, думать в парке, продавать в парке, быть в парке.
```

Подставляя различные глаголы, видим, что они все примерно одинаково (слабо) связаны со своим дополнением, значит это не их дополнение, а обстоятельство при глаголах.

```
Сидеть на стуле, думать на стуле, продавать на стуле, быть на стуле.
```

Подставляя различные глаголы, видим, что они все примерно одинаково(слабо) связаны со своим дополнением, но на их фоне выделяется первый глагол. По смыслу он сильно связан со своим дополнением в 1. Значит это дополнение. В остальных случаях обстоятельство.

```
Сидение на стуле, Думание на стуле, Продажа на стуле
```

Здесь соответственно 1. дополнение. 2. и 3. определения в функции обстоятельства.

```
Вход (дверь) в зал. // определение к существительному

Вход (вхождение) в зал. // дополнение к глаголу входить, и значит к глагольному существительному вход тоже дополнение

Приток инвестиций в город // дополнение - инвестиций (к глагольному существительному, ибо при глаголе "притекать" оно очевидно будет дополнением). Определение - город. (ибо при глаголе "притекать" оно очевидно будет обстоятельством)
```

Вот еще хорошая подборка на тему обстоятельство vs дополнение. См ответы Людмилы.

```
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430399

https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/45868

https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/35941
```

Comment: В первой категории примеров все понятно. Во второй уже есть вопросы: сидеть (на чём?) на стуле — связано по смыслу, согласен; думать (где?) на стуле — не связано по смыслу, согласен; продавать (на чём?) на стуле — стул используют в качестве предмета, на котором кто-то что-то продаёт, поэтому, как мне кажется, здесь дополнение. Идём дальше. Несогласованное определение. Слово вход, приведенный в твоём примере, сложно представить со значением входить, поэтому там определение. Предлаю такой вариант: Вход воспрещён — Входить запрещено.

Comment: Или: В тот же день состоялся, наконец, торжественный вход в Петербург войск, участвовавших в турецкой кампании. Ещё дальше. Пример подборов обстоятельство vs дополнение. В первой ссылке — дискуссия между Людмилой и Sharon по поводу определение vs дополнение. Во второй ссылке действительно годный совете — в копилку. В третьем ссылке тоже есть, что подчеркнуть — в копилку. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Да, как-то так. В догонку еще такое: продажа (отсчитывание денег) на стуле, это дополнение. продажа (сидя) на стуле, это обстоятельство образа действия. Игра в футбол на футбольном поле (дополнение). Игра в футбол на куликовом поле (обстоятельство)

Comment: «Продажа (отсчитывание денег) на стуле, это дополнение». — Согласен. «Продажа (сидя) на стуле, это обстоятельство образа действия». — Не согласен, потому что слово сидя не входит в состав предложения: в первом предложении подразумевается то, что на стуле что-то кто-то продаёт — во втором случае, что на нём не продают, а продают, сидя на стуле. «Игра в футбол на футбольном поле (дополнение)». — Не согласен. Здесь обстоятельство места, поскольку словосочетание на футбольном поле обозначает место, а не предмет, оно равносильно предложению учусь в школе.

Comment: Так вопрос только в том, что мы вкладываем во фразу. В одном случае "игра на поле" это определение (игра где), в другом это дополнение (игра на чем). В обоих случаях мы вкладываем и то (где) и другое (на чем) и вопрос лишь в степени того, что мы хотим выделить. Тут нет даже того, о чем поспорить, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Да и есть еще такой прикол: "Если бы словоформа входила в состав подлежащего, это было бы точно определение". Про это тоже не стоит забывать. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430399